# Can 5mm UV LEDs cure solder mask?

Tags: pcb, pcb-assembly

Is it possible to cure solder mask using about 32 5mm UV LEDs spread evenly above a PCB (10x15 cm). If yes, since they are weak, what would the cure time be?
I want to make my own PCB mill and I want to make them better by applying solder mask to them, and I’m wondering if what I want is possible, else I’ll have to buy a UV lamp. Keep in mind I have 35 UV LEDs already at me, so I just have to 3d print some parts and make the connections. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of commercial products using UV LEDs to cure solder mask. Check the datasheet for your solder mask, look up how much light is required to cure, and then buy appropriate LEDs to reach that level in the time you want to wait.

Comment: It’s a mechanic solder mask, I’m trying to find data for it right now, thank you!

Comment: Seems it needs 25mj/cm2, but I can’t find any info about the LED. I guess I’m just going to hope it works.

Comment: You should pick another LED that comes with information about its output.  That way you can confirm that it is correct for the application.

Comment: Depends on the LED. Buy ones that work, with a good datasheet--they really aren't that expensive.

Comment: Check the datasheet for wavelength. Cheap "360 nm" ones are well into 400 nm range and won't cure your soldermask.